# iPhone application pixelated on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios13, blurry

I've two live apps on Appstore, my one app is looking quite blurry on iPhone 11(which I just bought) and its fine previous models of iPhone, but my another app looks fine on iPhone 11.
The first app which is blurry is built on xib file and base screen size of iPhon SE and second app which look fine is built on storyboard and base screen size is iPhone 8 but I think that may not be the reason.

**Blurry App on iPhone 11 (as it look pixelated)** [image]

**Blurry App on iPhone 8(as it looks fine and crisp)**
[image]

**Xib file of Blurry App**
[image]

Let me know why this is happening and whats the solution ? Do I need to revamp all screens in project? Looking for suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: do you have a storyboard for launch-screen in your blurry app? if you don't have, just add one (and if necessary, make sure you have a auto-layout setting up nicely with the constraints).

Comment: We've set splash screens for LaunchImage in Images.xcassets

Comment: you will need to replace those with a `Launchscreen.storyboard` file.

Comment: I added Launch screen and yes it resolve issue but my app support iPad and iPhone all variants so iPad splash screen image is getting blurry because using launch screen have no feature to cover all iPad screen sizes unlike Launch Image in  Images.xcassets

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution and the culprit was **iOS 8.0 and Later** check. It was unchecked, which I marked checked and added Splash screens for these defined sizes and my whole apps screens became crisp from pixelated.

[image]